# stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters encodes colons

Tags: objective-c, url, cocoa

I wrote the following test code in objective-c:

```objectivec
   NSCharacterSet *pathAllowedCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet];

   // Check if colon is a member of URLPathAllowedCharacterSet
   if ([pathAllowedCharacterSet characterIsMember:':']) {
       NSLog(@"Colon is allowed in URL path");
   } else {
       NSLog(@"Colon is not allowed in URL path");
   }
   
   NSString* test = [@":" stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]];
   NSLog(@"%@", test);
```

What gets logged is

```
Colon is allowed in URL path
%3A
```

The documentation for `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` states:

> Returns a new string made from the receiver by replacing all characters not in the specified set with percent-encoded characters.

That implies to me that if a character is in the specified set, it will *not* be percent-encoded. Why is the colon being percent-encoded? Is there a way for it not to be?

Comment: FYI - consider using `NSURLComponents` to more easily and safely build URLs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44395835/7833793

Comment: Thanks. I guess that answer is what I need. However, I think this may be just a pure bug, since colon is included in `URLPathAllowedCharacterSet` but the function percent-encodes it anyway.